# How to echo the configurable product price?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

Im trying to echo the price of a configurable product in the description but it doesn't update when I select some options.

I have a bed thats starts at £149.00 and with each different size you select 2.6, 3', 4', 4'6", 5', 6' the price goes up by £20 - £150, but when I echo the price it only echos the base price of the configurable product and does not update the price when I select different sizes.

This is the code from

**app/design/frontend//default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

```
<?php 
 echo $_prodcut->getFinalPrice();
 echo number_format($_product->getFinalPrice(), '2', '.', ',');
?>
```

now Ideally I want the price to be echoed at the top where it is originally and at the bottom because on mobile customers are having to scroll to the top to view the adjusted price, and I simply want to echo it at the bottom aswell so they don't have to go back and forth, any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Basically this configurable has price render by  json  object and changing the options .price is changed.Magento coded for default drop system.You need to customization

Comment: Any ideas or tutorials to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it after paying a freelancer to do it for me but it works and might aswell share how he did it with the world, since no body would help me fix it.

Change line #738 of js/varien/product.js

```
jQuery('[id="'+pair.value+'"]').find('.price').text(formattedPrice) //$(pair.value).select('.price')[0].innerHTML
```

to

```
$(pair.value).select('.price')[0].innerHTML = formattedPrice;
```

and add

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; ">
    <?php 
        echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product);
    ?>
</div>
```

to whereever you want the price to be echoed again.